# Using preg_replace to remove unwanted links

Tags: php, parsing, preg-replace

I'm trying to remove something like this:

```
<a href="http://women.domain.com">women.domain.com</a>
```

I thought it should be:

```
$this->tresc[$i][description]=preg_replace("/\<a(.*)href=(\"|')http:\/\/women\.domain\.com.*(\"|')(.*)\/\>/i", "",$this->tresc[$i][description]);
```

but it doesn't work.

For images I use this and it's working perfectly:

```
$this->tresc[$i][description]=preg_replace("/\<img(.*)src=(\"|')http:\/\/women\.domain\.com.*(\"|')(.*)\/\>/i", "",$this->tresc[$i][description]);
```

Comment: this : preg_replace("/<.*>/", "hello", $this->tresc[$i][description]);

Comment: first of all you have to make the regex ungreedy by appending a U

Comment: and then you have to correct the tail of your regex in order to recognize the </a> that is absent in img tags

Comment: and this is all you have to do. Please don't ask this kind of questions on StackOverflow

Comment: You really don't want to be using REGEX to parse/manipulate DOMs. If the document is even slightly malformed, or you don't take every possibility into account, it will fail. REGEX is not a parser; PHP has some perfectly good DOM functionality.

Comment: @Utkanos: OP did not say "parse". That's what the meme says, not what the question requires. And there's no indication that this question is about arbitrary website manipulation more than output rewriting. Using the overkill solution for everything isn't very professional either.

Comment: @Mario - so you would disagree that, if the HTML he posted was malformed or otherwise unpredictable slightly, the result would fail?

Comment: @Mario - so the risks of using REGEX to pull out bits of HTML is fictional. Interesting standpoint... I think we're boring everyone, though, and this would better be moved to chat or ceased. I won't post again - feel free to have the last say.

Comment: Correct, this is a part of RSS reader and now some feeds stopped to work. I really need to remove only <a href=http://link.com>link</a>

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$this->tresc[$i][description]=preg_replace("/<a href=\"(.*)\">/i", "",$this->tresc[$i][description]);
$this->tresc[$i][description]=preg_replace("/<\/a\>/i", "",$this->tresc[$i][description]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$pattern = '(\<a href=["|\']+[http(s)?:\/\/]+([a-z0-9\-]+[.]){1,}+[a-z]{2,4}+[\/]+(.*)+["|\']\>+(.*)+\</a\>)';
$string = "click <a href='http://subdomain.sitename.tld/somedir'>here</a>";

var_dump(preg_replace($pattern, "", $string)); // prints "string 'click ' (length=6)"
```

Comment: @Spacedust it's an example of removing a link.

Comment: I did it in a shorter way. See below ;)

Answer (score -1):

```
$this->tresc[$i][description]=preg_replace("/\<a .*\>.*\<\/a\>/i", "", $this->tresc[$i][description]);
```